# Magento block override from two different modules

Tags: magento, overriding, block

Hi I have some issues in overriding a magento core block. In my module I need to override Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation

```
<blocks>
  <catalog>
    <rewrite>
            <navigation>Mycompany_Mymodule_Catalog_Block_Navigation</navigation>
        </rewrite>
  </catalog>
</blocks>
```

but this is already overridden by another magento extension from another company:

```
<blocks>
  <catalog>
    <rewrite>
        <navigation>Othercompany_Othermodule_Block_Navigation</navigation>
    </rewrite>
  </catalog>
</blocks>
```

Both extension overrides different methods and they don't know abut each other, but magento reads the second company overrides and not my. I don't want to use module dependencies. Is there any way to not break the two extensions functionality.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=magento+resolving+module+conflicts&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: The reason Magento read's the other company's is just luck - probably alphabetical order or something like that but see my response below on how to properly use both.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you have to decide which one officially overwrites the core Block. Have that one *inherit* the one that isn't doing the override, and have that one inherit the core one.

```
My_Custom_Block extends Other_Custom_Block
Other_Custom_Block extends Mage_Core_Block
Mage_Core_Block extends Whatever_Magento_Wants
```

Edit the config.xml files so that only My_Custom_Block is the one that is overriding the core Block.

**EDIT**
Here's the XML you need:

```
<blocks>
  <catalog>
    <rewrite>
            <navigation>Mycompany_Mymodule_Catalog_Block_Navigation</navigation>
        </rewrite>
  </catalog>
</blocks>
```

Comment: you should add the xml rewrite declaration, to have the complete answer

Comment: Can you please give me an example based on the code above (config.xml code) how this rewrite declaration should look like. Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Thx Max.
I think, like your example, that the "My_Custom_Block" should be the last hierarchic class, so you don't touch anythings in "Other_Custom_Block" class.

Then you have only to comment the rewrite rule in "Other Company" config.xml.